# zip extract all here (one click)

Tags: windows-registry, zip, context-menu, extract

It is amazing how many compressed files I end up working with, and while I know it is not a long process, I want to see if its possible to save some steps

Right now, its

```
right click
"Extract All..."
then click "Extract" button (wherever windows decides to put the dialog box today)
file extracts where I tell it to (always same location .zip is located)
```

I am looking to change it (edit the right click menu?)

```
right click
"Extract All..." (or change text to (make new option?) "Extract All Here")
file extracts in same folder as .zip was located
```

While I am only saving 1/3 the clicks, with the amount of times I extract from .zip it would save me a lot of clicks over time

I am not against downloading something third party that makes life easier, but I am not afraid to get into the registry to do it myself if I knew where/what to change

I should mention it is a Windows 10 Pro machine

Comment: 7-zip offers far more powerful features and you can right click and extract in one click.

Comment: Associated .zip with 7-zip, and now the process is open (double click), click extract, then confirm location (adding a click).. that's not better.. there is no context menu to "extract here" and the process isn't any faster/better... so unless you know a setting that will do what I want, i am going back to using windows for .zip

Comment: Don’t know what to say. 7-zip installs a context menu and it is quite robust. Maybe you skipped the option during installation somehow. See if this helps: https://superuser.com/questions/644372/missing-explorer-menu-options-for-7-zip. I haven’t had this issue.

Comment: it was my mistake, apparently when I first installed 7zip I had installed the x86 version instead of the x64.. the context menu items weren't there. I uninstalled and installed the x64 version and they are.  If you re-post your suggestion as an answer I will mark it accepted